# For a projective variety $X$, the open subset $X\setminus{Z(f)}$ is an affine variety for a linear homogeneous polynomial $f$, proof

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How do I show the following:

"Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^{n}$ be a projective variety, and let $f \in k\left[x_{0}, \ldots, x_{n}\right]$ be a linear homogeneous polynomial. Then $X \backslash Z(f)$ is an affine variety."

The Veronese embedding subsequently show that the statement holds for any homogeneous polynomial (claimed in the proof of theorem 3.4.12, from the pdf-script by A. Gathmann, version 2002-03 for any non-constant homogeneous polynomial).

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{P}^n \setminus Z(f) = \mathbb{A}^n$.

Comment: When $f\ne0$ by a change of basis you may assume $f=x_n$.